# Select only one items from array items - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm using fields_for and select methods, but this code doesn't have usability. This may be better using JSON, or js fielter`

```
<%=form_for @order do |f| %>
        <%@categories.each do |category| %>
            <% if category.produc

ts.any? %>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <h2><%= category.name%></h2>
                    </div>

                    <%= f.fields_for :order_items, @order.order_items.build do |oi| %>
                        <div>

                          Product: <%= oi.select :product_id, category.products.pluck(:title, :id) %>
                          Quantity: <%= oi.number_field :quantity, min: 1, value: 1 %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.submit "Create order" %>
        <% end %>`
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What do you want, what have you tried, what's not working as intended?

Comment: I have got 10 items how i show on page . I must select only one item from 10. How i can do this?